# Someone explain SharePoint features

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to create a SharePoint timer and deploy it via a SharePoint feature. I have a bunch of questions.

1. When I specify the local site to use for debugging do I enter the path to
   central admin or do I enter the path to a site?
2. The timer needs to process items in a list, I believe the list is in a
   specific site, so do I need to set the local site to that site URL or do I 
   set it to the root (a level above the site?)
3. Explain the scopes of a feature (Web, WebApplication, Site)
4. If I ever get a feature/timer to deploy where do I go to start/stop/etc?

I have followed countless tutorials and I run in to Access Denied errors when I deploy.
Or thanks to one tutorial I got a feature to deploy (a simple page that says "Hello World") but no idea where that page was deployed to.

SP is a dark horse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint timer scope is always `Web Application`

Your answers:

1. You set it to SharePoint site, not Central Admin.
2. Not the root, set it to specific site which contains list.
3. Web Application.
4. You can do it via stsadm.

Check out this article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798313.aspx

http://markanthonyparker.blogspot.in/2010/08/execute-sharepoint-timer-job-using.html

Comment: I am able to deploy when the scope is web, but when it is WebApplication I get an access denied error. Any harm in leaving the scope as Web?

Comment: You can leave it as web as well. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/792938/scope-of-a-timer-job-feature